# Pairing individuals from two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, data.table

I have two dataframes. The first consists of data from 10 individuals, while the second consists in 1000. Variables are the same between dataframes:

```
set.seed(2022)
SmallCohort <- data.frame("ID" = paste0("S00", sample(1000:9999, 10)),
                          "Sex" = sample(c("M", "F")),
                          "Age" = sample(20:30, 10, replace = TRUE),
                          "Smoke" = sample(c("Y","N")),
                          "Disease" = sample(c("Y","N")))

BigCohort <- data.frame("Subj" = paste0("B00", sample(1000:9999, 1000)),
                        "Sex" = sample(c("M", "F")),
                        "Age" = sample(20:30, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                        "Smoke" = sample(c("Y","N")),
                        "Disease" = sample(c("Y","N")))
```

My goal is to find paired individuals from the `BigCohort`. Basically, I need to choose 10 ***unique*** individuals from the `BigCohort` paired for `Sex`, `Age`, `Smoke` and `Disease` with the same number of individuals from the small cohort.

I'm not looking for propensity score matching.

I tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
Combined <- inner_join(SmallCohort, BigCohort)
```

Comment: This code did not achieve the goal! BTW thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did something similar yesterday! A simple loop and some **tidyverse** functions get the job done.

First, you are not using `sample` correctly in your example data, so let's correct that first:

```
set.seed(2022)
SmallCohort <- data.frame("ID" = paste0("S00", sample(1000:9999, 10)),
                          "Sex" = sample(c("M", "F")),
                          "Age" = sample(20:30, 10, replace = TRUE),
                          "Smoke" = sample(c("Y","N"), 10, replace = T),
                          "Disease" = sample(c("Y","N"), 10, replace = T))

BigCohort <- data.frame("Subj" = paste0("B00", sample(1000:9999, 1000)),
                        "Sex" = sample(c("M", "F")),
                        "Age" = sample(20:30, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                        "Smoke" = sample(c("Y","N"), 1000, replace = T),
                        "Disease" = sample(c("Y","N"), 1000, replace = T))
```

For every person in `SmallCohort`, the loop checks which people in `BigCohort` are exact matches for your chosen attributes (Sex, Age, Smoke, Disease). The first eligible matching person from `BigCohort` is chosen, if they haven't already been matched. This loop adds a column to `SmallCohort` called "BigMatch", which stores the appropriate match from BigCohort (this tracks the matches and stores the end result). You can also use this to pull the list of BigCohort matches as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

SmallCohort$BigMatch <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(SmallCohort)) {
  
  small.attributes <- select(SmallCohort[i, ], -ID, -BigMatch)
  
  big_matches <- BigCohort %>% 
    mutate(across(-Subj, ~.x == small.attributes[[cur_column()]])) %>% 
    filter(if_all(-Subj, ~. == T) & !(Subj %in% SmallCohort$BigMatch)) 
  
  SmallCohort$BigMatch[i] <- big_matches$Subj[1]
}

BigCohortMatched <- filter(BigCohort, Subj %in% SmallCohort$BigMatch)

SmallCohort
        ID Sex Age Smoke Disease BigMatch
1  S005323   M  21     Y       Y  B007379
2  S008885   F  26     N       N  B009542
3  S003870   M  25     Y       Y  B008244
4  S009899   F  24     N       N  B004840
5  S005869   M  20     N       N  B009496
6  S003750   F  22     N       N  B005087
7  S009998   M  20     Y       Y  B008961
8  S001475   F  21     Y       N  B006545
9  S001122   M  29     N       Y  B007727
10 S002271   F  26     Y       N  B008913

BigCohortMatched
      Subj Sex Age Smoke Disease
1  B007727   M  29     N       Y
2  B005087   F  22     N       N
3  B009542   F  26     N       N
4  B008961   M  20     Y       Y
5  B008244   M  25     Y       Y
6  B006545   F  21     Y       N
7  B008913   F  26     Y       N
8  B009496   M  20     N       N
9  B004840   F  24     N       N
10 B007379   M  21     Y       Y
```